# Change text color with Select/Option

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

I'm trying to change a text color, using the Select object, trying to get the color I selected and setting it to the text. There are two functions commented on my script, both were my attempts to get it done, but failed. Not asking for a complete answer/code, just want to know what is wrong.
This is the code and thanks for your time:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hola Mundo Controles</title>
        <meta name="author" content="José Del Valle Cordero"/>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="subject" id="subject">
                <span id="salute">¡Hello!</span>
            </div>
            <div id="control">
                 <div class="color_option">
                     Color:
                     <select name="color_list" id="colors" >
                         <option value="cl_option1" checked="checked">Red </option>
                         <option value="cl_option2">Blue </option>
                         <option value="cl_option3">Yellow </option>
                         <option value="cl_option4">Black </option>
                     </select>
                 </div>
             </div>  
         </div>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        var item,cl;
        var colorsMap = {
            'cl_option1' : "red",
            'cl_option2' : "blue",
            'cl_option3' : "yellow",
            'cl_option4' : "black"
        };

        /*colors.onchange=function() {
            var salute = document.getElementById("salute");
            var item = document.getElementById("colors").selectedIndex;
            var color = colorsMap[item];
            salute.style.color = color;

        };*/


        /*$('#colors').change(function(){
            var salute = document.getElementById("salute");
            item=$(this).val();
            cl = colorsMap[item];
           salute.style.color = cl;
        });*/        
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Your second commented block of code is semi-jQuery and that won't work unless you include jQuery.

Comment: Here's a fiddle I threw together: http://jsfiddle.net/pH4wW/ - The second function seems to be working? (After I make a change...)

Comment: OP just needs to include jQuery in his HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many thing has to be changed in the code.

If you are doing it with js

```
colors.onchange=function(){
      var salute = document.getElementById("salute");
      var item = document.getElementById("colors").selectedIndex;
      var color = colorsMap[item];
      salute.style.color = color;


  };
```

has to be changed to

```
document.getElementById("colors").onchange=function(){

      var salute = document.getElementById("salute");
      var item = document.getElementById("colors").value;

      var color = colorsMap[item];
      document.getElementById("salute").style.color = color;


  };
```

you have to attach onchange event using document.getElementById

if jquery

```
$('#colors').change(function(){

     var salute = document.getElementById("salute");
     item=$(this).val();
     cl = colorsMap[item];

     $('#salute').css('color', cl);
  });
```

Also you are missing jquery library.

Answer (score 1):

You're close. Include jQuery in `<head>`:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

Then in your JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var colorsMap = {
  'cl_option1' : "red",
  'cl_option2' : "blue",
  'cl_option3' : "yellow",
  'cl_option4' : "black"
};


  $('#colors').change(function(){
     $("#salute").css('color', colorsMap[$(this).val()]);
  });
  </script>
```

The original script is too clumsy & mixing up non-jQuery & jQuery functions.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest issue I see, besides your lack of jQuery being included in the page, is your js is being executed right away. Both of your attempts use js to talk to the DOM where those html nodes are, however, the DOM my not be ready with those nodes when your scripts are running.

[jQuery offers a way to do this](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) with a single line, if you prefer to go that route. If you want to learn native js, which I highly recommend, you'll want to [read up on](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onload) listening for when the window is ready.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions:

The first code block (non-jQuery) was using selectedIndex for your select element, which was returning a numerical value (the index value) of the selected item. You wanted the string value to check against your map of colors. Updating your code so it looks something like:

```
var colors = document.getElementById('colors');
colors.onchange=function(){
  var salute = document.getElementById("salute");
  var item = document.getElementById("colors").value;
  var color = colorsMap[item];
  salute.style.color = color;
}
```

will work.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pH4wW/2/

The second one, you just need jQuery :)